# How to split text and digit from a dataframe using for loop in r

Tags: r, regex, loops, sorting, split

I have a dataframe including text and digit and I want to split, sort and combine text and digit in the separate columns. Kindly find the example dataset.

```
Text
7 LIFTING & SHORING
-00 General
-10 Jacking
-20 Shoring
8 LEVELING & WEIGHING
-00 General
-10 Weighing and Balancing
-20 Leveling
```

I need to get the below results:

```
dig      Desc.
700      LIFTING & SHORING General
710      LIFTING & SHORING Jacking
720      LIFTING & SHORING Shoring
800      LEVELING & WEIGHING General
810      LEVELING & WEIGHING Weighing and Balancing 
820      LEVELING & WEIGHING Leveling
```

I tried in R with for loop but I'm a newbie in r and can't find any solutions.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: It won't be easy for a beginner to make the duplicate link work for this question. also, unfair downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(Text,c("text1","text2"),"^-") %>%
  mutate(text1 = ifelse(text1 == "", NA, text1)) %>%
  fill(text1) %>%
  filter(!is.na(text2)) %>%
  separate(text1,c("dig1","Desc1"),convert = TRUE,extra="merge") %>%
  separate(text2,c("dig2","Desc2"),convert = TRUE,extra="merge") %>%
  transmute(dig = dig1*100+dig2,
            Desc. = paste(Desc1,Desc2))

#   dig                                      Desc.
# 1 700                  LIFTING & SHORING General
# 2 710                  LIFTING & SHORING Jacking
# 3 720                  LIFTING & SHORING Shoring
# 4 800                LEVELING & WEIGHING General
# 5 810 LEVELING & WEIGHING Weighing and Balancing
# 6 820               LEVELING & WEIGHING Leveling
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="Text
'7 LIFTING & SHORING'
'-00 General'
'-10 Jacking'
'-20 Shoring'
'8 LEVELING & WEIGHING'
'-00 General'
'-10 Weighing and Balancing'
'-20 Leveling'",strin=F,h=T)
```

Comment: Moody, Thank you! I sent you an email with more detail information.

Comment: You're welcome, you should find out which rows are problematic and post an additional example with expected output as you did already. I believe that some of your rows don't start with dashes but expect a similar treatment, and my code expect these dashes as a first character, but i need reproducibe data (in text format, no pic) to do more.

Comment: This is the data link: 
  http://itlims-zsis.meil.pw.edu.pl/pomoce/ESL/2016/ATA_Chapters.pdf
and the parts of the data i need to extract

temp <- data.frame(Essai=pdf_text("ATA_Chapters.pdf")%>% strsplit(split = "\r\n") %>% unlist)

x = nrow(temp)

ata<- temp[90:x,]

ata <- as.character(ata)

df <- data.frame(Text=ata)

the output i want is exactly what you achieved.
Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant info in your question. You'll find great info here on how to do so : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example